# Xcode: debug step into key conflict (F7)

Tags: itunes, macos, keyboard, xcode, keybindings

I'm trying to debug using Xcode and how can I use Step Into (F7 key) with an external keyboard (not available FN key)?
If I click F7 iTunes restart current song...

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" in Keyboard Preferences.

[image: Keyboard Preferences]

Comment: ....uh... after probably 6 years or more I actually looked at the my external Apple keyboard and I've found the "fn" key...... btw, thanks!