# How to map function key (F1-F12) to perform like they do with builtin keyboard on Macbook

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have an USB external keyboard but the Fn(1-12) keys are kinda useless. I use my macbook in clamshell mode and I want to use the regular function like expose, etc.. using function keys.

Is this possibile with os x sierra?

Comment: Have you tried System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > Use all F1, F2 etc as standard function keys ?

Comment: See this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/202122/28424

Comment: @ecnepsnai what i want is eg. press f8 on external usb keyboard to play/pause. That option isn't exactly what i want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using the free tool [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to accomplish this. After you've installed it, go to the Function Keys tab and set each key's behavior as desired. Below is a replica of the default key behaviors on a 2014 MacBook Pro, for example. If you want to only remap the function keys on your external keyboard, then uncheck the internal keyboard in the Devices tab.

[image: Karabiner-Elements Preferences]